# Problem while imputing data in R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on [this](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2Factivity.zip) (52Kb) dataset.

Here, certain rows contain `NA` in the `steps` column. For imputing, I am taking a basic assumption that, I will take an average of `steps` in each `interval` across all dates, store that in the `interval_avg` df and then impute the average values corresponding to that interval.

This is how I tried doing this:

```
invisible(sapply(c('tidyverse','lubridate'),library,character.only = T))
data = read.csv(unzip('repdata_data_activity.zip'),
                colClasses = c('integer','Date','integer'))
summary(data)
```

So, there are 2304 NA rows in `steps` column and none in any of the other columns

Average steps in an interval:

```
interval_avg = data %>% group_by(interval) %>%
    summarise(Avg_steps = mean(steps,na.rm = T))
```

Imputing the data:

```
imputed_data = data %>%
    mutate(steps = if_else(is.na(steps),
                           as.integer(round(interval_avg$Avg_steps[interval_avg$interval == interval])),
                           steps))
```

But `summary(imputed_data)` tells that out of 2304 `NA` rows, 2016 rows haven't been imputed using the above approach. I'm confused what's wrong here

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code `interval_avg$Avg_steps[interval_avg$interval == interval])` is not accurate since length of `interval_avg$interval` is different from length of `data$interval`.

One way without creating `interval_avg` as separate dataframe would be to `replace` the `NA` values after grouping by `interval`.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(interval) %>%
  mutate(steps = replace(steps, is.na(steps), mean(steps,na.rm = TRUE)))

#     steps date       interval
#    <dbl> <date>        <int>
# 1 1.72   2012-10-01        0
# 2 0.340  2012-10-01        5
# 3 0.132  2012-10-01       10
# 4 0.151  2012-10-01       15
# 5 0.0755 2012-10-01       20
# 6 2.09   2012-10-01       25
# 7 0.528  2012-10-01       30
# 8 0.868  2012-10-01       35
# 9 0      2012-10-01       40
#10 1.47   2012-10-01       45
# … with 17,558 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful answer!

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of `na.aggregate` from `zoo`, which automatically replace the `NA` with the default `mean` option

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
data %>%
     group_by(interval) %>%
     mutate(steps = na.aggregate(steps))
```